A coupon problem from Sheldon Ross' "First Introduction to probability"
Question
Suppose that there are $N$ distinct types of coupons and that each time one obtains a
coupon, it is, independently of previous selections, equally likely to be any one of the
$N$ types.
1.) One random variable of interest is $T$, the number of coupons that needs to
be collected until one obtains a complete set of at least one of each type.
2.)  Let $D_{n}$ be another random variable which counts how many different types of coupons does a person get if $n$ coupons are distributed.
My doubt is in part 2. Here is how I did it:
My Attempt
Let $A_{j}$ denote the event that the $j$th coupon doesn't come to the person when $n$ coupons have been distributed to the person.  $P({A_{j}}^c) = 1-P(A_{j})$. Thus $P(\cap_{i = 1}^{k}{A_{j_{i}}}) = \prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-P(A_{j_{i}}))$  (using independence of $A_{j}$s). Thus, $P(D_{n} = k) = {N \choose k}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-P(A_{j_{i}})) = {N \choose k}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-\frac{(N-1)^{n}}{N^{n}})$
But according to Sheldon Ross, the above solution is wrong. I feel I am wrong to conclude that $A_{j}'s$ are independent.
1.) How to effectively conclude that whether $A_{j}'s$ are independent or not?
2.) How to solve the problem, I ain't able to follow Ross' solution, it seems to have written lots of lines which I feel I need to prove or somehow show.
3.) Is sheldon ross a good problem book to solve. I have read the theory of probability and statistics a lots of times, I need to solve hard problems but I want the solution to be elegant and understandable in case I am not able to do it on my own? Any suggestions?

How could those events be independent?  If I know I have received coupons $1$ through $99$, that takes up at least $99$ chances for me to have obtained $100$, making $A_{100}$ less likely than it would otherwise be.

Should say, your scenario isn't clear.  I am assuming that you are defining those events in the context of a fixed number of trials.  If, say, you only had one trial, then the $A_i$ are mutually exclusive, just stressing their dependence.

@lulu didn't understand whatever you said.

Consider the case $n=1$.  In that case, you obviously can only get one coupon. So if $A_1$ occurs, $A_2$ can not.  Thus, in that particular case, the $A_j$ are mutually exclusive, hence dependent.  The same phenomenon occurs for any $n$, though not to such an extreme degree.  Knowing that coupon $1$ appeared means that you have only $n-1$ or fewer slots in which to have seen coupon $2$.  Thus knowing that $A_1$ happened makes it less likely that $A_2$ happened, so again they are dependent.
